# socialauth android ResourceNotFound

Tags: android, socialauth

I am implementing socialAuth android in my application. But when i click my share button there is a error:

```
 01-07 19:25:27.308: D/SocialAuthAdapter(4167): Selected provider is facebook
 01-07 19:25:27.308: D/SocialAuthAdapter(4167): Loading keys and secrets from configuration
01-07 19:25:27.328: I/SocialAuthConfig(4167): Loading application configuration
01-07 19:25:27.358: I/OAuth2(4167): Determining URL for redirection
01-07 19:25:27.358: I/OAuth2(4167): Redirection to following URL should happen : https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=447809015285714&response_type=code&redirect_uri=fbconnect%3A%2F%2Fsuccess&scope=publish_stream,email,user_birthday,user_location
01-07 19:25:27.358: D/SocialAuthAdapter(4167): Loading URL : https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=447809015285714&response_type=code&redirect_uri=fbconnect%3A%2F%2Fsuccess&scope=publish_stream,email,user_birthday,user_location&type=user_agent&display=touch
01-07 19:25:27.358: D/SocialAuthAdapter(4167): Callback URI : fbconnect://success
01-07 19:25:27.368: W/ResourceType(4167): No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000000
01-07 19:25:27.368: D/AndroidRuntime(4167): Shutting down VM
01-07 19:25:27.378: W/dalvikvm(4167): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a9c210)
01-07 19:25:27.378: E/AndroidRuntime(4167): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-07 19:25:27.378: E/AndroidRuntime(4167): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
01-07 19:25:27.378: E/AndroidRuntime(4167):     at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1023)
```

More log.

```
01-07 19:25:27.378: E/AndroidRuntime(4167):     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:668)
01-07 19:25:27.378: E/AndroidRuntime(4167):     at org.brickred.socialauth.android.SocialAuthDialog.setUpTitle(SocialAuthDialog.java:149)
01-07 19:25:27.378: E/AndroidRuntime(4167):     at org.brickred.socialauth.android.SocialAuthDialog.onCreate(SocialAuthDialog.java:123)
01-07 19:25:27.378: E/AndroidRuntime(4167):     at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:353)
01-07 19:25:27.378: E/AndroidRuntime(4167):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:257)
01-07 19:25:27.378: E/AndroidRuntime(4167):     at org.brickred.socialauth.android.SocialAuthAdapter$3$1.run(SocialAuthAdapter.java:372)
01-07 19:25:27.378: E/AndroidRuntime(4167):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
01-07 19:25:27.378: E/AndroidRuntime(4167):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-07 19:25:27.378: E/AndroidRuntime(4167):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-07 19:25:27.378: E/AndroidRuntime(4167):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4441)
01-07 19:25:27.378: E/AndroidRuntime(4167):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-07 19:25:27.378: E/AndroidRuntime(4167):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-07 19:25:27.378: E/AndroidRuntime(4167):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:823)
01-07 19:25:27.378: E/AndroidRuntime(4167):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:590)
01-07 19:25:27.378: E/AndroidRuntime(4167):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

And i have no idea why is that happening.
I have followed very carefully after examples.

Comment: Can you post more of the stack trace? You cut it off where it gets interesting.

Comment: you don't include the resources. how do you include socialPath in your app ?

Comment: i copy `.jar` files in `libs` folder  then i `Build Path`. No other resources used...

Comment: Seems like you are setting an invalid resource somewhere. I need to see some code. What happens when you press that button?

Comment: @katzoft i dont handle what will happen when button is clicked, i even dont set click listener, its all done in library.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Please put Icon for facebook,Google, twitter with name facebook.png,foursquare.png,google.png,linkedin.png,myspace.png,twitter.png,yahoo.png int res folder.

Answer (score 3):

Just put on your Image (**facebook.png , linkedin.png , twitter.png or many more who your integrate with your app**) drawable folder.

This problem occur because on your lib file require icon and if its not here on your package then its shows error.

```
No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000000
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0

at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:668)
at org.brickred.socialauth.android.SocialAuthDialog.setUpTitle(SocialAuthDialog.java:149)
```

above i m just shown u main error which occur when file is not here on your drawable.